# Filtering Facebook Ad Campaigns to get those with delivery in Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to get the list of campaigns that have had delivery within a given time range. I can get the list of ALL campaigns within a time range - but need help in figuring out how to filter them.

Here is my current code:

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

my_account = objects.AdAccount('act_XXXXXXXXXXXXX')
print my_account


today = datetime.date.today()
threeDaysAgo = today - timedelta(days=3)


#get list of campaigns from FB
cparams = {
    #'effective_status':['ACTIVE'],
    'time_range': {
        'since': threeDaysAgo.__str__(),
        'until': today.__str__()
    }
}
clist = my_account.get_campaigns(params=cparams)
```

This gets me ALL the campaigns during the time range. However, I need to get only the ones that have had delivery. How do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to do so -- use the insight edge.

Here is how:

```
fields = [
    Insights.Field.campaign_id,
    Insights.Field.campaign_name,
    Insights.Field.spend,
]

today = datetime.date.today()
threeDaysAgo = today - timedelta(days=3)
params = {
    'time_range': {'since': threeDaysAgo.__str__(), 'until': today.__str__()},
    'level': 'campaign',
    'limit': 100
}

insights = my_account.get_insights(fields=fields, params=params)
```

Then we can loop over insights - to get the campaign ID:

```
for i in insights:
    print "Processing ..." + i['campaign_id']
    cid = i['campaign_id']
```

and then process the campaign and data and in any way we want ...

```
 campaign = Campaign(cid + "")
```

and ...

```
campaign.remote_read(fields=[
            Campaign.Field.name,
            Campaign.Field.effective_status,
            Campaign.Field.objective,
        ])
```

Hope it helps.